# Best way to assign Jquery events to Dynamic buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap

I am generating twitter bootstrap modals dynamically based on the user action (Long Story). Lets say some times user can see 100 modals on his screen. In each and every modal I have 5 dynamic buttons, each have it own purpose and did same in all modals, and have different id's.

I am attaching onClick events to those buttons by using jquery when ever there is a new twitter modal opens up by using the button id as follows

```
$(document).on("click","#btn"+btnNumber, function(){
   //Code Goes Gere
});
```

So If I open 100 modals, each have 5 buttons, Is it good idea to assigning click events for 500 times ?

or Is it good Idea to assign click events by using it's name attribute for 1 time as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","btnNameAttr", function(){
       //Code Goes Gere
    });
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052310/jquery-assign-events-to-buttons/22052379#22052379

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery on() can help you in this. First you need to detach appending DATA to your element ID like `btn+btnNumber`. You can add your custom information in any `data-x` attribute like `data-custom-info` and use the jQuery `attr('data-custom-info')` syntax to retrieve the information. The event handlers registered with `on()` method is also available for future elements(elements created after script execution). Like below.

When creating new button, add render it as..

```
<input .... class="btnWithData" data-custom-info="1" ... />
<input .... class="btnWithData" data-custom-info="2" ... />
```

and your event handler goes like..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('click','.btnWithData',function(){
//DO WHATEVER
var buttonData=$(this).attr('data-custom-info');
//DO WHATEVER
 });
});
```

Comment: I think you have your on parameters reversed, it should be .on('event', 'selector', handler). http://api.jquery.com/on/ And you have two periods instead of one in the selector :)

Comment: Yeah that's right. Sorry about that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Best is don't use closures they require memory. Rely on good old data tags, instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#wrapper").on("click", "btnNameAttr", function () {
    var n;

    n = $(this).data("number");
    // code goes here
  });
});
```

To differentiate the actually clicked element inside `#wrapper` you use `data-number` attributes like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img data-number="000" />
  <img data-number="001" />
  <img data-number="002" />
  <img data-number="003" />
</div>
```

This code will perform much better and you can still have all functionality you want by using wrapping `<div>` elements and `data-number=""` attributes. And you don't interfere with `class` or `id` attributes you might already have on those elements.

You can even add the command to the tag:

```
<img data-number="000" data-command="edit" />
<img data-number="000" data-command="show" />
<img data-number="000" data-command="delete" />
```

And switch on it:

```
switch ($(this).data("command"))
{
  case "edit":
    // edit element with number n here
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign **delegated event listeners** using `jQuery.on()` method as @Ananthan-Unni suggests, but in the form:

```
$.on('click', 'button', listener)
```

In this case you do not need to assign unique ids or attributes. You can use tag name or class name as a selector (2nd argument).

Have a look here: https://api.jquery.com/on/ and read on **delegated events**.