# JQuery assign events to buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have 50 dynamically generated HTML buttons as follows:

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" name="myButton" value="Click Me" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" name="myButton" value="Click Me" />
:
:
:
<input type="button" id="btn50" name="myButton" value="Click Me" />
```

Which is the best way to assign click event to all buttons using jQuery?

By using `id` or by using `name` attribute ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is the behaviour different for each button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051813/best-way-to-assign-jquery-events-to-dynamic-buttons

Answer (score 9):

Event listeners cost memory. You have to think carefully about how you should implement the listeners.

**1. The straightforward way:**

*Do not use this*

If the behaviour for each button is the same, use a class:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

If behaviour for each button is different, assign events to different #IDs

```
$("#btn1").click(function {
    // Do something
});
```

**2. Use .on():**

jQuery 1.7 introduced .on() method that wraps all listeners to 1 method.

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    // Do something
});
```

However, we are still binding many listeners on the page.

**3. Use a wrapper (use this!):**

Wrap your buttons with a div and create one listener for it.

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", "button", function() {
    // Do something
});
```

**Useful resources:**

- [Performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/jquery-event-delegation)
- [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I'm not disputing the performance comparison you linked to but I'd like to point out that it's **only** comparing the time it takes to bind the events, not handle them. Nor is it comparing memory related. I'm not disputing anything I just wanted to add that bit of information.

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to delegate to the surrounding container, that way you only have one listener rather than 50. Use `.on()`

https://api.jquery.com/on/

If you must assign to each button, figure out a way to write only one selector, like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){});
```

Note your selector may need to be more specific to target just these 50 buttons, as @Drewness points out in the comments.

Comment: The only problem with using `$('button')` is there may be other buttons on the page that do not apply.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Answer (score 1):

I would apply it to the parent element of the buttons. So if all of the buttons were in `<div id="myButtons">`:

```
$('#myButtons').on('click', 'button' function () {
    // Do stuff...
});
```

The key is to be specific enough that you do not have to specify each selector **but** not too lose as there may be other buttons, etc. on the page that you do *not* want to include.

Updated code to include delegation.

Comment: This doesn't add a handler for #myButtons though, it adds a handler for each button that's a direct descendant of #myButtons.

Comment: @BillF. - Right, which is what the OP wants, "...assign click event to all buttons..."

Comment: But that's 50 handlers, as opposed to one.

Answer (score 1):

if you have all the buttons inside of a container and you want the same function for all add the click handler to the container

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PB7LT/1/)**

```
$("#container").on("click", function(e){
    if(e.target.type =="button")
    {
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
});

<div id="container">
    <input type="button" id="test1" value="button1"/>
    <input type="button" id="test2" value="button2"/>
    <input type="button" id="test3" value="button3"/>
    <input type="button" id="test4" value="button4"/>
    <input type="button" id="test5" value="button5"/>
    <input type="button" id="test6" value="button6"/>

    something 
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to have an if statement here. $("#container").on("click", "button", function(e) {});

Answer (score 1):

This would be an easy way to wrap it all up into one 'on' event and do something based on the button id;

```
<button id='button1'>button 1</button>
<button id='button2'>button 2</button>
<button id='button3'>button 3</button>


var mybuttons =  $('#button1');

for(i=1;i<3;i++){
    mybuttons = mybuttons.add($('#button'+i));
}
console.log(mybuttons);

mybuttons.on('click', function(){
    var myid = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(myid);
    //use a switch or do whatever you want with the button based on the id;
});
```

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gisheri/CW474/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better if you use a common class name for all and handle click event by that class name.

```
$('.classname').click(function(){
    //`enter code here`
});
```

Or you can handle event by tag name:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    //'enter code here'
});
```

This method might effect the function of other buttons which are not included in the group of 50 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use following code:

```
 $("#btn1").on("click",function(){
      // Your code
 });

 $("#btn2").on("click",function(){
      // Your code
 });
```

and so on...

Comment: if I have 1000 buttons means, I'll have to assign 1000 handlers ? It decreases the performance of the application

Comment: If you have the common function to execute for all buttons then you can do by using just single line of code:

 $("#btn1, #btn2, #btn3, ....").on("click",function(){
      // Your code
 });

Comment: So you have to add to the selector each time you add another button? May as well put this in the onclick attribute of the HTML.

Comment: Then use this $("input[type='button']").on("click",function(){ // Your code }); 

In this way you don't have to add selector each time you add new button.