# jQuery .click method doesn't work on <a> that was already made by previous method

Tags: php, jquery, html, onclick

HTML:

```
<div id="ajax_search_add_button_div">
    <a id="ajax_search_add_button" style="cursor: pointer;">Add</a>
</div>

<div id="ajax_search_added_items">
    Selected Items:
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nr.</td>
            <td>Item Name</td>
            <td>Amount</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript 1

```
$("#ajax_search_add_button").click(function() {
    $("#ajax_search_added_items table").append('<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td><a id="ajax_search_remove_button" style="cursor: pointer;">remove</a></td></tr>');
});
```

Javascript 2

```
$("#ajax_search_remove_button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Why nothing is happening when I press the "remove" button? When I click on "add" button, then "Javascript 1" method starts, but when I click on "remove" button, the "Javascript 2" method doesn't start.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery assign events to buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052310/jquery-assign-events-to-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Event Delegation**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for newly created elements.

```
$(document).on("click","#ajax_search_remove_button",function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: Sadly, but it still isn't working. I tried to do the same in the jsfiddle and there everything works, but not in my website..

Answer (score 0):

You need event delegation for dynamically created elements. so use `.on()` along with `click`:

```
$(document).on('click',"#ajax_search_remove_button",function() {
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your element is added dynamically so it is not present at the time DOM ready or page load.

So you have to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

like this

```
$(document).on('click','#ajax_search_remove_button',function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

or Better

```
$('parentElementPresesntAtDOMready').on('click','#ajax_search_remove_button',function(){
   // code here
});
```

---

```
$('#ajax_search_added_items').on('click','#ajax_search_remove_button',function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```