# How to affect the HTML code inserted by jQuery on runtime?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Actually I have an example code for HTML and jQuery:

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1' />
<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='try.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="overall">
<br>hello<br>
</div>

<div id="endoverall"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add new Hello" id="button">

</body>
</html>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button').click(function(){
    var content = '<div id="overall"><br>hello<br></div>';
    $('#endoverall').before(content);
});

$('#overall').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Basically I want the page in which whenever someone clicks on "Add new Hello" button, the #overall div should insert before endoverall and also as per jQuery, whenever someone clicks on that newly insert hello, it should give an alert of it.

The code I've given here is working and add the #overall div, but the alert is not working.

Comment: 1) You can't have more than one ID, use classes. 2) Look up event delegation for elements added on-the-fly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052310/jquery-assign-events-to-buttons/22052379#22052379

Comment: @cept0 Why is this a poor question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ahren summed it all up for you, I'm only going to put in a bit more information.

1) You cannot have `id`s repeating multiple. `id` is unique to each element alone, thus we use classes so you would do:

```
var content = '<div class="overall">
```

2) You are adding new elements after the page load, in this case the newly created elements do not have the `click` handler binded to it, so we use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to add the event handler.

```
$(document).on('click','.overall',function(){
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dbn6d/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code generated multiple elements with same ID. Remember that each ID must be unique.
2. Use same class if the functionality is going to be the same for all buttons.
3. You need to use event delegation to be able to attach the `click` event to newly created elements.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
    <div class="common"><br>hello<br></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#wrapper").on("click", "div.common", function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bjc93/1/)**